# Java HTTP POST request to a public https:// web service

Tags: java, http, post, https

I try to send a POST request to a public https:// web service.
This is my code snippet:

```
static void xPostJsonUsingHttpClient() 
       throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String anafURL = 
    "https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v2/ws/tva";
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(anafURL);

    String json = "[{\"cui\":19,\"data\":\"2017-11-07\"}]";

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");

    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(response);

    client.close();
}
```

Being a https:// adress I don't know, what I have to change?
Postman or SoapUI works fine with it.

When I run my code, it terminates with error:
***javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target***

Have I to download a public key or just I have to make some additional settings?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Does the code not return what you expect?  What is your question?

Comment: I modified my post.
Please see the error message.

Comment: How recent is your Java?  The SSL certificate uses a certificate authority certificate that is from late April of 2015.  Hopefully your Java is up to date but if not that could be the reason.

Comment: Of course my Java is up to date.
I will try to use the solution given by  Beno Arakelyan (see below) .

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but I believe your JVM does not recognize the CA of the certificate that this web server uses. I ran into the same problem a while ago and what helped was the following:

The URL you are trying to connect to, uses "certsign.net" as Certificate Authority.

1. Download the CA from [certsign](http://www.certsign.net)!
2. Then import it using [this guide](https://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store)!

After that you should be able to connect. If not let me know.

Comment: I answered the question while you updated it. Given the error message, my solution should definitely work.

Comment: Thanks. 
Probably this isnát the right solution for me.

Comment: Thanks. 
Olthougs it works, probably this isn't the right solution for me.
I need this program to work on my clients computer (few hundred), making as few modifications on their computers as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

```
rivate static final HttpRequest<?> HTTP_REQUEST = 
 HttpRequestBuilder.createPost("https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v2/ws/tva")
        .trustAllCertificates()
        .trustAllHosts()
        .addDefaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())
        .addContentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .build();

@Test
public void test() {
    ResponseHandler<?> responseHandler = 
            HTTP_REQUEST.executeWithBody("[{\"cui\":19,\"data\":\"2017-11-07\"}]");
    assertEquals(SC_OK, responseHandler.getStatusCode());
}
```

Status code is OK. You can use `String` or sometype instead of wildcard type if you want to get response body. See the documentation.